# P5js: why is my bg framerate not refreshing properly?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have 2 sets of code in here. One is the simple bounce off code. The other is a function. I've tried to make it a function but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

1. The bg framerate doesn't clear in the sense that a string of balls show rather than a ball bouncing and animating.
2. `if(this.y_pos > 400)` this condition doesn't seem to be working even tho it works when it is drawn in the draw function.

```js
        var sketch = function (p) {
          with(p) {

            p.setup = function() {
              createCanvas(800, 600);
                
              //    x_pos = 799;
              //    y_pos = 100;
           
              //    spdx = -random(5,10);
              //    spdy = random(12,17);
            };
        
            p.draw = function() {
              background(0);
              
              //    fill(255);
              //    ellipse(x_pos,y_pos,50);
              //    x_pos += spdx;
              //    y_pos += spdy;
                 
              //    if(y_pos > 400)
              //    {
              //        spdy *= -1;
              //    }
              
              // for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
              
              avalance(799, 100, random(5,10), random(12,17));
            };

            function avalance(x, y, spdx, spdy)
            {
                this.x_pos = x;
                this.y_pos = y;
                this.spdx = spdx;
                this.spdy = spdy;
                
                this.x_pos = 799;
                this.y_pos = 100;
                
                this.spdx = 1;
                this.spdy = 1;
                
                this.movement = function()
                {
                    this.x_pos += -spdx;
                    this.y_pos += spdy;
                    
                    if(this.y_pos > 400)
                    {
                        this.spdy *= -1;
                    }
                }
                
                this.draw = function()
                {
                    this.movement();
                    this.drawnRox();
                }
                
                this.drawnRox = function()
                {
                    fill(255);
                    ellipse(this.x_pos,this.y_pos,50);
                }
                
            }


            
          }
        };
        
        let node = document.createElement('div');
        window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
        new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
    body {
      background-color:#efefef;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <div id="p5-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's address both issues:

1. The `draw()` function is called for each new frame and in it you call `avalance` which creates a new ball. To fix that you need to

- Create a global variable `let ball;` out of `setup()` and `draw()` so that you can reuse that later;
- In setup create a new ball and assign it to your `ball` variable: `ball = new avalance(799, 100, random(5,10), random(12,17));`
- In `draw()` you want to update the ball and that's what its own `draw()` function does (I would advise renaming it `update()` for example, to avoid confusion with the p5 specific `draw()` function). So you just need to call `ball.draw()` in `draw()`.

This creates a ball which moves but still don't respect your 400px limit.

2. The issue is that in `movement()` you add `spdx` and `spdy` to the position but when the ball crosses the limit you update `this.spdy`, so you need to update the function with this code:

   this.x_pos += -this.spdx;
   this.y_pos += this.spdy;

And you should be good! [Here is](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/YzqrbaN?editors=0011) a code pend with your code working as you intend.

Also as a bonus advise: You probably want to use some [p5.Vector](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) objects to store positions, speeds and accelerations it really makes your code easier to read and to use. You could also rename your function `Avalance` (capital `A`) to show that you actually use a class and that this function shouldn't be called without `new`.

Answer (score 0):

As @statox suggested, do `new avalance(799, 100, random(5,10), random(12,17))` in the `setup()` section and call `draw` of the `ball` in `draw()` section.

You can test the code below by clicking "Run code snippet".

```js
        var sketch = function (p) {
          with(p) {

            var ball;

            p.setup = function() {
              createCanvas(800, 600);
                
              ball = new avalance(799, 100, random(5,10), random(12,17));
            };
        
            p.draw = function() {
              background(0);

              ball.draw();
            };

            function avalance(x, y, spdx, spdy)
            {
                
                function movement ()
                {
                    x += -spdx;
                    y += spdy;
                    
                    if (y > height || y < 0)
                    {
                        spdy *= -1;
                    }
                    if (x > width || x < 0)
                    {
                        spdx *= -1;
                    }
                }
                
                this.draw = function()
                {
                    movement();
                    drawnRox();
                }
                
                function drawnRox ()
                {
                    fill(255);
                    ellipse(x,y,50);
                }
                
            }


            
          }
        };
        
        let node = document.createElement('div');
        window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
        new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
    body {
      background-color:#efefef;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <div id="p5-container"></div>
```